# How to underline string via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, underline

I am working on a project involving Javascript and I need a string to be underlined. The code has the word "Date" in front of the current date (represented by the variable `now`). The current date needs to be underlined, not the word "Date".

This is the code I am using:

```js
var now = new Date();
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = "Date " + (now.getMonth()+1)+ "/"+ now.getDate()+ "/"+ now.getFullYear();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *When something with the ID of "date" is found...*

Use **CSS** for presentation:

```css
#date {text-decoration: underline;}
```

**Snippet**

```js
var now = new Date();
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = "Date <span>" + (now.getMonth()+1)+ "/"+ now.getDate()+ "/"+ now.getFullYear() + "</span>";
```

```css
#date span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Also, please note, there should not be any duplication of `id`s. So if there are multiple `date` elements in the same page, use `class` instead and style this way:

```css
.date {text-decoration: underline;}
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: One issue. The entire string is underlined if you do it this way. I want just the date underlined, not "Date" and the date.

Comment: @AChildofGod You have to enclose the `Date` inside, say `<u>` tag?

Comment: I am also using a span tag with an ID of "date" to display it. It works. Had I wanted the entire string to be underlined, I wouldn't be asking a question. I could easily style it with the span tag.

Comment: @AChildofGod Change your code to: `.innerHTML = "<u>Date</u> " + `

Comment: @AChildofGod You are using full line without any differentiation to the Date. See the above comment and try changing your code accordingly.

Comment: I don't think you understand. The text that says "Date" is not to be underlined. The rest of it is.

Comment: @AChildofGod `document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = "Date <u>" + (now.getMonth()+1)+ "/"+ now.getDate()+ "/"+ now.getFullYear() + "</u>";`

Comment: Okay, I see. Will try it out

Comment: @AChildofGod Waiting for that... Just the code is enough. Don't copy the CSS for now.

Comment: When I did that, only the word "Date" showed. What was supposed to be underlined did not appear at all

Comment: @AChildofGod Lemme update it in the answer, and you tell if it is the right thing...

Comment: That should have worked, except it didn't. Perhaps it has something with me using Google Chrome or the script is inside of an XHTML file.

Comment: I changed things up a bit and used your CSS idea. I finally got what I want.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too.